# How to launch code editor when it is keep loading forever?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I can not launch into code editor as it keeps loading forever. I am a beginner and was trying to open this [repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples) in code editor of GCP. Then it has been loading until now.

I tried to click top-right, then Restart
top-right, then Enable Safe Mode
top-right, then Enable Boost Mode
None of them works.

This is how my screen looks like:

[image: screen]

System: Ubuntu

Comment: A gut guess is that because this is such a huge repository, it may be that the Cloud Shell code editor is trying to "scan" the complete directory structure and examine all the source files which (if true) may be too much for it.

Comment: Nope (to my last comment).  I cloned the repository in cloud shell and was able to open the cloud shell editor in real-time with no issues.